# What are the long metal things in stores that hold products that hang from them?

Tags: meaning, terminology

What are the long metal things in stores like Walgreens that hold things like gummy bears or nuts or hair clips? The metal things are straight and then at the end they curve up, and they are connected to the wall to carry things without using shelves.

Comment: I don't know, but you could research "point-of-purchase" displays, maybe.

Comment: It depends on who's talking.  In general they're called "racks" or "hooks" by most people but in catalogs that sell retail merchandising equipment, they will have more specific names.  I was a stock boy at Woolworth's in high school, which closed shop in the US about 25 years ago. If a paperback book didn't sell, management would tear off the cover and return it to the publisher for a credit, and toss the book in the trash. I got dozens and dozens of free books that way.

Comment: I would have called them simply "hooks" (background, Montreal Canada for 30+ years, the US (New England and Texas) for another 30+ years). The "hook bar" description in @Xanne's answer seems to be an assembly that has several hooks attached to it.  At Walgreens, I've noticed that they use a "Peg board" (https://www.uline.com/BL_2409/Pegboard-Accessories) into which the hooks or hook bars fit.

Comment: Google "retail rod hooks" or "retail peg hooks" and this may be what you are looking for?

Answer (score 9):

They’re called hook bars. Here’s an ad for one variety.

See [here](https://www.midwaydisplays.com/hook-bar-with-graphic-arm-4-flip-scanner-hooks.html).

Comment: The small parts of the display racks used to hang items are often called [display hooks](https://www.google.com/search?q=display+hook).

Comment: What they're calling a "hook bar" is the whole contraption: the black frame containing four hooks. In other words, this answer is incorrect.

Comment: @Marthaª Yes, I think you’re right. I haven’t found terms that distinguish types of hooks.  It’s such a specialized area of equipment that the question is in fact not suitable for this forum.

Answer (score 2):

They are called "Pegs" in my experience (UK / British).

Comment: There's pegboard hooks, sure. But the hundreds of other patented systems all have their own nomenclature because of the patent restrictions on infringement.

Comment: I don't think I can improve on this, but I think what MikeB is referring to is the "things" that you push into pegboard, like this: https://www.amazon.com/TORACK-Pegboard-Organizer-Toolboard-Accessories/dp/B08MT9LWMB/. There the "things" seem to be referred to as "hooks" (or "pegboard hooks"), more like Xanne's answer.

Comment: @PhilSweet  Pegboard is a generic term these days - no idea what you mean by patented systems. Pegs may originally have had longer names, but that is what the things that 'product' hangs off is known as to the staff that use them.